# Fancyhdr not detecting first and last \markboth on page correctly

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

## Problem

I have created tex template adding dictionary style header to pages, this means it contains the first and the last entry from a page.
So far everything worked fine, but when I added optional parameter with alternative text (for the header) to the entry, the first and last entries on pages are not calculated correctly:
On page 1, alternative text from the first entry on page 2 is displayed in the header,
and on page 2 alternative text from the second and last entries on page 2 is displayed in the header.

**This is how page 1 header looks like:**
[image: Page 1 header]

**This is the bottom of page 1, and page 2 header:**

[image: Bottom of page 1, and page 2 header]

When I remove the alternative text from a2 entry, the headers are correct (a - a1 on page 1; a2 - a on page 2). I can even add alternative text "b1" to a1 entry, and it will be correctly displayed in the header (a - b1 on page 1; a2 - a on page 2).

## Question

Can you see anything wrong with my code or is it a bug in fancyhdr library?

### Code reproducing the issue:

I am running the following through XeLaTeX

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=1.85cm,top=1.85cm, bottom=1.85cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand\entry[3][]{\ifx\relax#1\relax\par\hangpara{1em}{1}\markboth{#2}{#2}\else\par\markboth{#1}{#1}\fi\textbf{#2} #3}

\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textbf{\ifthenelse{\equal{\rightmark}{\leftmark}}{\rightmark}{\rightmark\ -- \leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\textbf{\thepage}}
\begin{document}
\RaggedRight
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a1}{ - no alternative text}%
\entry[b2]{a2}{- b2 as alternative text}%
\entry[b3]{a3}{- b3 as alternative text}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\entry{a}{}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are issuing your \markboth in vmode, after a \par. And that means that it can be separated from following text.

Use `\leavevmode\markboth`, or move the \markboth behind or inside the \textbf.

A current LaTeX contains extended support for marks. The documentation can be found in ltmarks-doc.pdf.

Answer (score 4):

The legacy commands \leftmark and \rightmark have limited flexibility

- \leftmark is always picking the last mark from the page (coming from the last \markboth)
- \rightmark is always picking the first mark on the page coming from the first \markboth or \markright
- \topmark is not supported (and never was) because it is a primitive command that only works in plain TeX but not LaTeX as it assumes that the output routine is never called unless you ship out a page. If you use it you get the values of both arguments of \markboth (hence the double "b2")

The reason that you see odd marks is because your \markboth commands are not attached to the text so the last mark on the page is in fact \markboth{b2}{b2}. You can easily see that if you do \showoutput and look for the mark commands. You can also see that with \DebugMarksOn.

Anyway, with the old system you simply couldn't do dictionary headings because \topmark was not functional. With the new implementation you can but not by using \topmark but by using the new commands \TopMark \FirstMark and \LastMark and the mark classes 2e-left, 2e-right and 2e-right-nonempty. These predefined classes are filled by \markboth and \markright, thus \TopMark{2e-left} gives you the "top" situation on the page.

But the new mechansim has much finer control and you can get marks for the columns and you can define your own classes and then use \PutMark instead of the legacy commands.

All this is explained in ltmarks-doc.pdf as Ulrike said and also in a number of examples in the new LaTeX Companion 3rd edition which I'm glad to say has now a publishing date of April 28, 2023.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a LaLeX bug. The marks handling in LaTeX has recently been greatly overhauled, so it wouldn't surprise me to find a bug in it. I hope the LaTeX developers will look into it, or maybe I should just file a bug report.

What I see when tracing and looking at the code is that the b2 entry goes to `\topmark`, even doubled (i.e. `\topmark=b2b2`) on the second page. The b3 entry then goes to `rightmark`. On the first page, surprisingly, `\leftmark=b2`, even though the `b2` doesn't occur on this page.

You can see this easily by replacing the `\fancyhead[LE,RO]` entry with `\fancyhead[LE,RO]{topmark=\topmark / leftmark=\leftmark / rightmark=\rightmark}`.

Comment: There is no bug Pieter. The \topmark primitive is not a supported LaTeX command, it never worked and it can't work because it assumes that the output routine is never called unless you ship out a page. So topmark doesn't reflect what it does in plain TeX because LaTeX calls the OR several times per page. Furthermore, marks are always structured (with left and right component) so what is in the last mark on the page is \mark{{b2}{b2}} which gives you the topmark you see on page 2. \leftmark and \rightmark pick one of these brace groups only. Do \showoutput to see that result matches input.

Comment: Yes, I know Frank. I was just surprised to see explicit assignments to `\topmark` in `latex.ltx`.

Comment: It is a primitive TeX command. This is done by the engine not by LaTeX just like \botmark and \firstmark get a value the moment you enter the OR.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach I was thinking of this piece of code `\let\topmark\@firstcoltopmark}`. In my tracings I saw this being executed. But just like Ulrike mentioned in her answer, I had already discovered that the `\markboth`'s in the original problem were wrongly placed. So this discussion is actually moot.